# How to validate if user is already connected through OAuth2 SSO Server?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, hydra

I have an `Hydra SSO Server`, an `OIDC Provider` and a `Resource Server Website`.

- When a user browses a protected page on the `Resource Server Website`, if no authentication info can be found, a guard will redirect the user to `Hydra SSO Server` and a `authorization-code` oauth2 flow will start. Either it will automatically log the user if `Hydra SSO Server` session can be found, either it will redirect the user back to the login page.
- When a user browses a public page on the `Resource Server Website`, the guard does not redirect the user to `Hydra SSO Server`. In this case we don't know if the user is already logged (`Hydra SSO Server` session is active).

As I would like to put user info on the `navbar` no matter which page he visits, what is the best approach to check user session on `Hydra SSO Server` ?

I did not find any endpoint for validating the user hydra session without redirection.

If I need to start with an oauth2 redirect against hydra when the website loads, is this a correct approach ?